# Active Directory | Keyboard Issues

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to enter anything in Active Directory.

But I can't type anything from keyboard.

By using mouse I can copy and paste.

I am using Windows 11.

Try to close the task manager and opened again.

Can anyone help how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

how are you? I have some questions about this.

1. If you have try type with virtual keyboard, what the behavior?
2. is a application crash or not? Sometimes, if you have research for many objects, the active directory can crash the next time when you open it. Try open it from another machine. This works?

Let me know about news